# How can I implement Places and PlaceLikelihoodBuffer in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I need to import/implement above mentioned classes, but cant seem to simply write

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihoodBuffer;
```

If I do that it states that they cannot be resolved. By what I have encountered earlier I suspect that I need to add something else, like in the manifest or such, but I cant seem to find exactly what.

The code which needs these imports look like this and is taken from Googles tutorials.

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            //@Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                int i = 0;
                mLikelyPlaceNames = new String[mMaxEntries];
               mLikelyPlaceAddresses = new String[mMaxEntries];
                mLikelyPlaceAttributions = new String[mMaxEntries];
                mLikelyPlaceLatLngs = new LatLng[mMaxEntries];
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    // Build a list of likely places to show the user. Max 5.
                    mLikelyPlaceNames[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName();
                    mLikelyPlaceAddresses[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress();
                    mLikelyPlaceAttributions[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                            .getAttributions();
                    mLikelyPlaceLatLngs[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng();

                    i++;
                    if (i > (mMaxEntries - 1)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Release the place likelihood buffer, to avoid memory leaks.
                likelyPlaces.release();

                // Show a dialog offering the user the list of likely places, and add a
                // marker at the selected place.
                openPlacesDialog();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you added `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0'` to your `build.gradle`?

Comment: I had not. Thank you!